# SQL Server 2008: how can I sort Month column by fiscal year

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone help me to sort the "month" column of the following script by fiscal year? For example, for Fiscal 2016, '07/15' should come first and '06/16' comes last. Thanks!

```
SELECT 
    RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), closed_dt, 3), 5) AS "MONTH", 
    Count(facility_id) COUNT 
FROM   
    facility 
WHERE  
    closed_dt BETWEEN @FromDate AND @EndDate 
GROUP BY 
    facility_status, RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), closed_dt, 3), 5) 
HAVING 
    facility_status IN ( 'CLOSED' )
```

Comment: There isn't even an order by in your query. We can't really offer much help here unless you provide some details. This might help. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Just add `ORDER BY closed_dt` at the end

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to add a another column

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), closed_dt, 3), 5) AS [MONTH]
      ,Count(facility_id) as [COUNT]
      ,max(closed_dt) as SortCol
FROM   @facility 
WHERE  closed_dt BETWEEN @FromDate AND @EndDate 
GROUP  BY facility_status
         ,RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), closed_dt, 3), 5) 
HAVING facility_status IN ( 'CLOSED' ) 
Order by SortCol
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a style of  'dd/mm/yy' in your convert.   You just need to cast the last two characters as int for the sort:

```
ORDER BY  CAST(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), closed_dt, 3), 2) as int),
RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), closed_dt, 3), 5)
```

This will sort by year first then your mos/yr ... a little sloppy, but should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I got an error message  'Closed_Dt' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause